# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings' in Django on NGINX / uWSGI

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

Django 2.2 running on Ubuntu 16.04 / NGINX / uWSGI / Python 3.6

I keep getting:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'` in the uWSGI error logs when trying to `reload` uWSGI.  Also, uWSGI will restart without an error message, but it won't `reload`.  Even when it `restart`s, however, the problem app is not started.

uWSGI configuration file:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /var/sites/mysite
module = mysite.wsgi
virtualenv = /opt/virtualenvs/mysite_venv
processes = 5
vacuum = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed in the uWSGI error log that Python 3.5 was being invoked before it set the virtual environment.  I resolved the problem with the following lines in the uWSGI config file.

```
plugins-dir = /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/
plugin = python36
```